# Nuxt.js robots.txt file Multiple disallow per user agent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, robots.txt

Using Nuxts [nuxt-robots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-robots) module how do I configure multipe disallows per user agent. Currently I have :

```
  robots: () => {
    return {
      UserAgent: '*',
      Disallow: '/search/',

      Sitemap: (req) => `https://${req.headers.host}/sitemap.xml`,
    }
  },
```

but I need to output:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /testimonials/

User-agent: MJ12bot
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /testimonials
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want several elements, you probably need to use an array.

Isn't something like this working?

```js
robots: () => {
  return [
    {
      UserAgent: '*',
      Disallow: '/search/',
      Sitemap: (req) => `https://${req.headers.host}/sitemap.xml`,
    },
    {
      UserAgent: 'MJ12bot',
      Disallow: '/search/',
      Sitemap: (req) => `https://${req.headers.host}/sitemap.xml`,
    },
  ]
}
```

Like the array approach: https://github.com/fengsi-io/nuxt-robots#array

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifying the Disallow paths as an array within the robots configuration.

```js
robots: {
  rules: {
    UserAgent: '*',
    Disallow: ['/auth/', '/settings', '/search'],
  },
},
```

The output from this configuration will be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /auth/
Disallow: /settings
Disallow: /search
```